# Prevent repeat post calls in short succession

Tags: angular

I've got a case where user can update a value as many times as they like, however I want to avoid spamming the server until user basically stops changing the value.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Use Case Example

HTML

```
Your New Value is {{value}}
<button (click) = "value = value+1">Increase By 1</button>
```

TS

```
const newData = {finalValue: this.value};
this.http.post(this.apiEndpoint, newData).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

My one thought is to use Subject to achieve this, but if there is a simpler way would be good to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`debounce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce) to delay sending the HTTP request if the user clicks again on the button.

Alternatively, you may need [`throttle`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttle) in case you want ignore any changes the user makes in between a time interval you set.

Comment: I tried debounce but not throttle, i must be doing something funky